# curl parses my json object in --raw-data as its arguments

Tags: curl

I'm trying to post data to an API using curl, I'm using this bash script:

*script.sh*

```bash
send_command () {
        echo "{\"cmd\":\"$@\"}" 
        curl --request POST \
                 --data-raw "{\"cmd\":\"$@\"}" \
                 -H "Content-Type: application/json"\
                 "http://localhost:8080/addCmd/" 
}

command_1 () {
        send_command test_command \
        -I {{files1}} \
        ---files1 'my_file.txt'\
}
```

after sourcing from *script.sh* then running `command_1` in the terminal, I get this error:

```
{"cmd":"test_command -I {{files1}} ---files1 my_file.txt"}
curl: option ---files1: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

I changed `---files1` to `--files1` and it produces the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"$@"` expands to multiple words (see [2.5.2 Special Parameters](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02) of the POSIX shell language specification).

Consequently, `--data-raw "{\"cmd\":\"$@\"}"` expands to more than 2 tokens if you passed multiple parameters to your function. For instance, invoking `send_command a 'b c' d` will expand to the following tokens:

```
'--data-raw' '{"cmd":"a' 'b c' 'd"}'
```

Which means that `'b c'` and `'d"}'` will be parsed as distinct parameters to curl.

If you want all parameters to expand to a single word, use `"$*"`:

```
curl --data-raw '{"cmd":"'"$*"'"}'
```

(or the equivalent `--data-raw "{\"cmd\":\"$*\"}"`, depending on whether you prefer to escape nested quotes.)

But this will still break when one of your parameters contains a double quote, because the result will be invalid JSON.

If you need to generate/construct JSON, I recommend using [jq](https://github.com/jqlang/jq):

```
jq -nc --arg cmd "$*" '{$cmd}' | curl --data-raw @-
```

or

```
curl --data-raw "$(jq -nc --arg cmd "$*" '{$cmd}')"
```

This does not suffer from the same limitations and will properly escape any embedded quotes in your input.

Or, if you have [HTTPie](https://httpie.io/) available:

```
http :8080/addCmd/ cmd="$*"
```

Comment: thanks `curl --data-raw '{"cmd":"'"$*"'"}'`  worked for me, I'm not planning to use double quotes in my parameters, so I didn't test the `jq` part.